# Is it possible to recover from an error returned by a data source?

Tags: terraform, hcl

Let's take the [`dns_a_record_set` data source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/dns/latest/docs/data-sources/dns_a_record_set), for example, if one does:

```hcl
data "dns_a_record_set" "test" {
  ## Purposely passing a DNS that would not resolve
  host = "thisDnsDoesNotResolve.org"
}

output "test" {
  value = data.dns_a_record_set.test.addrs
}
```

The error returned is, as expected:

> ```
> Error: error looking up A records for "thisDnsDoesNotResolve.org": lookup thisDnsDoesNotResolve.org on 1.1.1.1:53: no such host
> │ 
> │   with data.dns_a_record_set.test,
> │   on main.tf line 1, in data "dns_a_record_set" "test":
> │    1: data "dns_a_record_set" "test" {
> ```

But, is it possible to recover from this error and have the `test` output assigned with a *default* value?

---

A naive trial of mine was to use the [`try` function](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/try), but that obviously does not work, as the error does not happens when data is accessed, but rather when fetched, as shown in the error above.

```hcl
output "test" {
  ## Seems like it doesn't even reach here 
  value = try(data.dns_a_record_set.test.addrs, ["127.0.0.1"])
}
```

So, is this even possible to recover from this error?
And, then, how?

Comment: The literal answer is no, because that error is returned from the provider. This is also why the `try` function will not work, because that will rescue errors at the Terraform config. You would need to modify the provider code to supply a default if no value was Read, but this may also not be the full behavior you even want since that would also occur in situations where the argument values were incorrect. This would all require a lot of subtlety.

Comment: All that being said, this feature is requested so often that TF core may eventually implement more dynamic capabilities for the control behavior resulting from data Read.

Comment: That's a bit what I feared, but, thanks for the thorough explanation @MattSchuchard!

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of data resources in Terraform is to declare dependencies on objects managed elsewhere and, as a side-effect, obtain information about them to use in other parts of your module in a similar way as you might with objects that are managed *by* your current module.

If your module only depends on this DNS record in certain situations then a typical approach would be to use either the [`count`](https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/count) or [`for_each`](https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/for_each) meta-argument to explicitly declare in which situations your module depends on this object and which situations it doesn't.

It's hard to show a specific example without more information about your underlying motivation for this, but here's a contrived example where the hostname can be directly provided by the module caller as an input variable, and the dependency on that external object is only relevant when that variable is set (non-null):

```
variable "hostname" {
  type    = string
  default = null # this variable is optional
}

data "dns_a_record_set" "test" {
  count = length(var.hostname[*])

  host = var.hostname
}

output "ip_addresses" {
  value = one(data.dns_a_record_set.test[*].addrs)
}
```

The above uses two additional language features I didn't mention yet in this comment, which I'll describe briefly for completeness:

- Applying [the splat operator](https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/splat) `[*]` to a non-list value converts the value to be a list which either has one element (if the value is non-null) or zero elements (if the value is null). Therefore there will be one instance of this data resource if and only if `var.hostname` is non-null.
- [The `one` function](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/one) does essentially the opposite of that: if given a one-element list it will return the first element, and if given a zero-element list it will return `null`.

These two features taken together allow you to concisely pivot between values that might be null and lists of zero or one element, which is useful in situations like this where the "null-ness" of a valid decides how many of something should be declared.

---

Note that the `try` function only "catches" expression evaluation failures. It isn't relevant to this situation because what failed was the declared dependency on the external object; the error was returned when Terraform asked the provider to retrieve the `dns_a_record_set` object, not in the downstream expression which referred to that.

(Indeed, Terraform would never actually evaluate that expression in your case, because when there's a dependency from object B to object A, a failure of object A halts processing before reaching object B.)

Comment: I see why you would be reasoning like this, but the underlaying requirement is inverted: something like _if I don't have that DNS resolving, then don't a host creation_, and not _if I don't have that host, don't try to resolve this DNS_. If that makes any sense.

Comment: I think that is _kinda_ working against the design goals of the Terraform language, which is more aimed at allowing you to declare what you expect to be true and have Terraform check that it is, rather than to _react_ to what may or may not be true by declaring different infrastructure. Since Terraform is a desired state system, it's primarily designed for describing a _desired stable state_, whereas reacting to the presence or not of a DNS record would mean that e.g. an intermittent DNS failure would cause Terraform to propose to delete whatever is declared only when that DNS record exists.

Comment: In principle there could be a data source which is implemented to return null when the thing doesn't exist, rather than returning an error, but that's not a typical expectation of a data source in Terraform and so I would think of that as a workaround for an exceptional situation rather than a real solution. If you have this need, it may be better to address it with some other software, used either instead of Terraform or in combination with Terraform.

Comment: (By "in combination" I mean something like: a thing which tests the condition you want to work with, passes the result into Terraform as an input variable, and then ideally freezes that decision somewhere so that the answer can't "flap" on future runs.)